# Bluetooth speakers also connecting as headset

Tags: bluetooth, speakers, headphones

I have a bluetooth speaker that I use with my (Win 10) laptop for listening to music.  I also have a headset (not bluetooth) that I use for Teams calls, etc.  However, the speaker seems to be identified as a headset too.  After connecting it I sometimes find I can't hear anything or be heard in calls, and it turns out Teams has changed to the speaker as device for both output and input (interestingly, I don't even hear the other person in this case).

Anyway, the Bluetooth settings in Windows list "connected voice, music" for the device. But the only options I have are disconnect or remove device. On my phone (Android) I can specify, per device, what to use it for.  I want to use this one for music but not voice. Is there any way to change what it is used for in Win 10?

I know how to change the device in teams. What I want is to tell Windows never to use this device for voice, so I don't have to keep changing teams.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open MS Teams and make a test call so that MS Teams will appear in the Windows app specific sound settings list.
2. Hit <kbd>Windows logo key</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> then <kbd>y</kbd> to go to the ***Windows operating system*** Settings > System
3. Then go to > Sound > Advanced sound options > (App volume and device preferences)
4. You should now be in the Windows operating system "App volume and device preferences" setting dialog where you can select the Default Output and Input device for all Windows apps, including MS Teams.

Comment: Sorry, should have been clearer. I know how to change the device in teams. I want to tell the OS *never* to use this device for voice, so I don't have to keep changing teams

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my answer to make it more clear that I was referring to settings in the Windows operating system.  Not MS Teams.

Comment: OK.  Will try that.  Seems odd it has "voice, music" but doesn't let you choose :)

Comment: Sorry, doesn't work.  Have done that.  Teams is set to my actual headset, not default device, but still keeps resetting when the bluetooth speakers connect.